# Return Class which includes Fragments

Tags: java, android, fragment

I want to Override the public function getItem(int position):

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Tab1Content tab1 = new Tab1Content();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    Tab2Content tab2 = new Tab2Content();
                    return tab2;
                case 2:
                    Tab3Content tab3 = new Tab3Content();
                    return tab3;
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

Tab1Content looks like this:

```
public class Tab1Content extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_content, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

But Android Studio throws Error in Logs:

```
Error:(141, 28) error: incompatible types: Tab1Content cannot be converted to Fragment
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add below imports line in adapter :

`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;`
And in Fragment Class add below imports :

`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment should be extending the `android.support.v4.Fragment`.

And apart from that, you should use an Empty Constructor in your fragment.

You can also use newInstance method if you want to pass some data in your fragment:

In Fragment:

```
   public static TestFragment newInstance(int type) {

        TestFragment f = new TestFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("type", type);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }
```

Your `getItem` would look like this:

```
@Override public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return TestFragment.newInstance(1);
            case 1:
                return TestFragment1.newInstance(2);
            case 2:
                return TestFragment2.newInstance(3);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

`TestFragment1` and `TestFragment2` is similar to your `TestFragment`.